# How can I make my CPT read from page-*post-type*.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, pages

I have a CPT created. I made a page that uses `page-upcoming-games.php`. I have a query written on there to pull posts from my CPT. The issue I'm having is I have no idea how to make the slug `/upcoming-games/` read that page, it keeps taking me to `archives.php`. I had my urls messed up before and I know `page-upcoming-games.php` works, I just need to get the page to read that template.

Here's part of my CPT code:

```
'rewrite'               => array( 
                        'slug'                  => 'upcoming-games',
                        'with_front'            => false,
                        'pages'                 => true,
                        'feeds'                 => false,
                        ),
```

Here's the [live site](http://www.stepyouraimup.com/upcoming-games/), if that help's in any way.

Comment: Does `page-upcoming-games.php` also include `the_content()` from the actual page, or just your CPT loop? If only the CPT loop, there's no need to use a page template; rename that file to `archive-upcoming-games.php` (assumption: your CPT is "upcoming-games") and it will automatically be used when navigating to /upcoming-games/. If you are using the Page content as well, you'll need to change the value of `'slug'` in your `'rewrite'` arg. More info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: So create archive-upcoming-games.php and paste the code I have from page-upcoming-games.php? I'm using the CPT loop.

Comment: This makes sense. So it's the 'slug', okay. I updated the template file and it worked. Thanks.